# ActionButton that show/hide a toolbar? Firefox SDKfor addon

Tags: sdk, firefox-addon-sdk

Is it possible? I want to create an ActionButton which show or hide (depends it state) a Toolbar. Someone knows how? some function?

```
var mainButton = ActionButton({
id: "temp",
label: "temp",
icon: {
    "16": "./icons/bug.png",
    "32": "./icons/bug.png",
    "64": "./icons/bug.png"
},
onChange: enableToolbar})

var mainToolbar = ui.Toolbar({
title: "main",
hidden: true,
items: []})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [CustomizableUI.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/CustomizableUI.jsm): there is a function you can use to [set toolbar visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/CustomizableUI.jsm#setToolbarVisibility%28%29) knowing its id.

To import it jut do:

```
var {Cu} = require("chrome");
const { CustomizableUI } = Cu.import('resource:///modules/CustomizableUI.jsm', {});
```

Comment: I have imported var CustomizableUI = require("resource:///modules/CustomizableUI.jsm"); and tried: CustomizableUI.setToolbarVisibility("main","AREA_MENUBAR") but i get an error "CustomizableUI.setToolbarVisibility is not a function"

Comment: I don't know if `CustomizableUI.setToolbarVisibility("main","AREA_MENUBAR")` would work because I don't know if "main" is a valid toolbar id but I've edited my answer to let you know how to import CutomizableUI component.